# (New) React Context from a Nested Component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm having serious issues with the "new" React Context ( https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html ) to work like I want/expect from the documentation. I'm using React v.16.8.6 (upgrading will probably take ages, it's a big app). I know there is a bit of a mix between old and new stuff but plz don't get stuck on that..

I did it like this to be as flexible as possible but it doesn't work.

**The issue is**, when it comes to `contextAddToCart(..)` it only executes the empty function instead of the one I defined in state as the documentation `this.addToCart`. I have consumers in other places as well. It seems like perhaps it's executing this in the wrong order. Or every time a Compontent imports `MinicartContext` it's reset to empty fn.. I don't know how to get around this..

I'll just post the relevant code I think will explain it best:

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');
module.exports = function config(env, argv = {}) {
  return {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        'node_modules',
      ],
      alias: {
        contexts: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/contexts.js'),
      },
```

**contexts.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const MinicartContext = React.createContext({
  addToCart: () => {},
  getState: () => {},
});
```

**MinicartContainer.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {
  MinicartContext,
} from 'contexts';

export default class MinicartContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.addToCart = (product, qty) => {
      const { prices } = product;
      const { grandTotal, qtyTotal } = this.state;

      this.setState({
        grandTotal: grandTotal + prices.price,
        qtyTotal: qtyTotal + qty,
      });
    };

    this.state = {
      grandTotal: -1,
      qtyTotal: -1,
      currencyCode: '',
      addToCart: this.addToCart,
    };
  }    

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <MinicartContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {children}
      </MinicartContext.Provider>
    );
  }
```

**Header.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  MinicartContext,
} from 'contexts';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MinicartContainer MinicartContext={MinicartContext}>
          <Minicart MinicartContext={MinicartContext} />
        </MinicartContainer MinicartContext={MinicartContext}>

        {/* stuff */}

        <MinicartContainer MinicartContext={MinicartContext}>
          <Minicart MinicartContext={MinicartContext} />
        </MinicartContainer MinicartContext={MinicartContext}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Header;
```

**AddToCartButton.jsx**

```
import {
  MinicartContext,
} from 'contexts';    

export default class AddToCartButton extends Component {

  addToCart(e, contextAddToCart) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const QTY = 1;
    const { product, active } = this.props; 

    // doing stuff ...   

    contextAddToCart(product, QTY);
  }

  render() {       
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MinicartContext.Consumer>
          {({context, addToCart}) => (
            <div
              onClick={(e) => { this.addToCart(e, addToCart); }}
```

Comment: I think that is confusing tha you have several functions called the same, passing the values up and down, Have you tried the reducer pattern? or just creating the functions in the context and just consuming them as you need?

Comment: @OZZIE Are you sure AddToCartButton component is mounted under MinicartContainer component in the react tree? I can't see it here in the code.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the code you posted what the issue may be.  You may not be correctly connecting to your context.  If I had to guess you probably just have an issue with the function itself.  Here is a working example that is close to what you have.  Maybe it will help https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-gates-qox4c

Comment: Another thing that I missed in my answer: On your `Header.jsx` file, ween using the `MinicartContainer` and `Minicart`, remove the `MinicartContext` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was that I was using `<MinicartContainer>` in multiple places but all should act as one and the same. Changing it so it wrapped all elements made other elements reset their state when the context updated.

So the only solution I found was to make everything `static` (including state) inside `MinicartContainer`, and keep track of all the instances and then use `forceUpdate()` on all (needed) instances. (Since I am never doing `this.setState` nothing ever updates otherwise)

I though the new React context would be a clean replacement for things like Redux but as it stands today it's more a really vague specification which can replace Redux in a (sometimes) non standard way.

**If you can** just wrap all child `Consumer`s with a **single** Provider component without any side-effects then you can make it a more clean implementation. That said I don't think what I have done is bad in any way but not what people expect a clean implementation should look like. Also this approach isn't mentioned in the docs at all either.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you don't have fully understand how the context API words.

Here's my HOC implementation of contexts, maybe it can help you to understand better how things work.

```
export const MinicartContext = React.createContext({}) // Export the Context so we can use the Consumer in class and functional components (above). Don't use the Provider from here.

// Wrap the provider to add some custom values.
export const MinicartProvider = props => {
  const addToCart = () => {
    //Add a default version here
  };
  const getState = () => {
    //Add a default version here
  };

  // Get the custom values and override with instance ones.
  const value = {addToCart, getState, ...props.value}

  return <MinicartContext.Provider value={value}>
    {props.children} 
  </MinicartContext.Provider>
}
```

Then when using the provider:

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
  const addToCart = () => {
    //A custom version used only in this component, that need to override the default one
  };

  //Use the Wrapper, forget the MinicartContext.Provider
  return <MinicartProvider value={{addToCart}}>
    /* Stuff */
  </MinicartProvider>

}
```

And when using the consumer you have three options:

**Class Components with single context**

```
export default class AddToCartButton extends Component {
  static contextType = MinicartContext;

  render (){
    const {addToCart, getState} = this.context;
    return (/*Something*/)
  }
}
```

**Class Components with multiple contexts**

```
export default class AddToCartButton extends Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <MinicartContext.Consumer>{value => {
        const {addToCart, getState} = value
        return (/*Something*/)
      }}</MinicartContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

**Functional Components**

```
const AddToCartButton = props => {
  const {addToCart, getState} = useContext(MinicartContext);
}
```

You can create the Wrapper Provider as a class component too, and pass the full state as value, but it's unnecessary complexity.

I Recommend you take a look at [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87) about contexts, and also, avoid using the same name on the same scope... Your **AddToCartButton.jsx** file was reeeeally confusing :P

Comment: In the Consumer does it have to be named 'value' or can you put anything there? Or does it have to be the same name as in the Provider?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Toug's answer, I would memoize the exposed `value` prop of the provider.  Otherwise it will re-render it's subscribers every time even if the state doesn't change.

```
export const MinicartContext = React.createContext({}) // Export the Context so we can use the Consumer in class and functional components (above). Don't use the Provider from here.

// Wrap the provider to add some custom values.
export const MinicartProvider = props => {
  const addToCart = () => {
    //Add a default version here
  };
  const getState = () => {
    //Add a default version here
  };

  // Get the custom values and override with instance ones.
  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({addToCart, getState, ...props.value}),
    [addToCart, getState, props.value]
  );

  return <MinicartContext.Provider value={value}>
    {props.children} 
  </MinicartContext.Provider>
}
```